# how set the record number field in Integer format in Crystal Report using C#?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am using record number from formula field for SerialNO.Recordenumber shows the values in decimal format like 1.00,2.00 etc, but I like show that in 1,2 etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the field formatter? Crystal reports field formatter (right click the field and from the context menu, select format) and set how the number should be shown.

Comment: Thank You very much Mr.Kangkan I Got it from you reply

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not really a number, but more of an index you can treat it as text:

```
ToText({SerialNO.Recordnumber},0)
```